# How to get external form data into an angular 2 application

Tags: angular, redirect, angular-routing, angular-http

A redirect link with form data are sent to my angular application from an external application.

ex:
Redirect Link => https://myapp/#/payment/success (POST request)

Form data => **id=14434900&orderId=490738**

How can I get this **form data** into my angular application?

Comment: is this in url the `id` && `orderId`

Comment: no its form data showing as 'view source' in google chrome

Comment: add a image here of view source i am not able to see `https://myapp/#/payment/success`

Comment: if its a redirect link, i think you need to add those value as querystring of the redirect url...then you get in your angular application

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have access to that external API